# What is the cause of error "EBADENGINE" when installing new shopify app

Tags: node.js, npm, shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to create a new app on my local environment following shopify's official document https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/getting-started/create

I believe i have laterst version of NPM/Node installed on my machine.
[NODE and NPM installed on my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnzq8.png)
Error Codes:

`5358 error code EBADENGINE 5359 error engine Unsupported engine 5360 error engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: rollup@3.28.0 5361 error notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: rollup@3.28.0 5361 error notsup Required: {"node":">=14.18.0","npm":">=8.0.0"} 5361 error notsup Actual:   {"npm":"7.6.0","node":"v18.12.1"} 5362 verbose exit 1`

[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4OSj.png)

This issue occurred when I tried to install new app using shopify CLI.

Comment: Upgrade your npm to 8.x.x.